# How can I parse stringify data in php laravel controller

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

The data is passed from the HTML form to the laravel controller
I rendered addon checkbox dynamically like

```
data.add_ons.map(async (item, i) => {
                            addOnHtml += `
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between border-bottom pt-2">
                                <div>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="addon${i}" class="addonCheck" name="addon[${i}]" value='${JSON.stringify(item)}' data-price="${item.price}">
                                    <label for="addon${i}" style="font-size: 18px;margin-left:5px"> ${item.name}</label>
                                </div>
                                <h5>
                                    $${item.price}
                                </h5>

                            </div>`
                        })
```

The request I received in controller, I want to parse stringify addon array to json data

```
{
  "addon": [
    "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"pepsi\",\"price\":10,\"created_at\":\"2022-12-09T18:12:35.000000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2022-12-09T18:12:35.000000Z\",\"restaurant_id\":1,\"status\":1}",
    "{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Extra Cheese\",\"price\":4,\"created_at\":\"2022-12-14T18:16:48.000000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2022-12-14T18:16:48.000000Z\",\"restaurant_id\":1,\"status\":1}",
    "{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"Additional Fries\",\"price\":14,\"created_at\":\"2022-12-14T18:17:48.000000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2022-12-14T18:17:48.000000Z\",\"restaurant_id\":1,\"status\":1}"
  ],
  "product": "1",
  "type": "product",
  "quantity": "1",
  "purchase_type": "addtocart",
  "_token": "SNkipeuJwfn58IWpFYWNRo9Fx1nGzJnwGXENaLR0"
}
```

```
    $addons = [];
    foreach($request->addon as $addon){
        array_push($addons,json_decode($addon));
    }
    
    return $addons;
```

This code worked for me but I don't think it's the best approach to use foreach. Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: If it works, whats the problem? There is nothing wrong with that code, except I would have done `$addons[] = json_decode($addon);` and saved the overhead of a function call and return

Comment: the addon data seems to be double-encoded. If something you wrote created it like that, I would alter it to avoid this problem in the first place

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't have any problem, read my question correctly, I want to ask if is the right approach or not.

Comment: @ADyson I passed this data from the HTML form

Comment: You must have done something to mangle it then, so that it double-encoded some of the data. That doesn't happen by default.

Comment: `I want to ask if is the right approach`..."right" in terms of what? If it's working for you, what do you need to know exactly?

Comment: Hammad, for many things in development, specially trivial things like this, there are often multiple ways of doing the same thing, so there ___is often no RIGHT way of doing something___ it often comes down to personal preference, or the way a group like to see code written

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you so much for the explanation. I just wanted to know the other ways :)

Comment: Then my answer will show you one other way :)

Comment: Ah so in `value='${JSON.stringify(item)}'` of the checkbox you have already stringified the whole item. But...why do you need to send the whole item into the form and then send the whole item back again, unmodified? Just put the item's `id` as the value of the checkbox. Then your PHP code can retrieve the rest of the data about the add-on (if it actually needs it) when it receives the IDs in the posted data from the form. That's normally how HTML forms work. This also has the benefit that malicious users can't modify the form data to their advantage in any way (e.g. by altering the price!).

Answer (score 1):

Actually you could do the json conversion all in the original `$request` object.

```
$str = '{
    "addon": [
      "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"pepsi\",\"price\":10,\"created_at\":\"2022-12-09T18:12:35.000000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2022-12-09T18:12:35.000000Z\",\"restaurant_id\":1,\"status\":1}",
      "{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Extra Cheese\",\"price\":4,\"created_at\":\"2022-12-14T18:16:48.000000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2022-12-14T18:16:48.000000Z\",\"restaurant_id\":1,\"status\":1}",
      "{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"Additional Fries\",\"price\":14,\"created_at\":\"2022-12-14T18:17:48.000000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2022-12-14T18:17:48.000000Z\",\"restaurant_id\":1,\"status\":1}"
    ],
    "product": "1",
    "type": "product",
    "quantity": "1",
    "purchase_type": "addtocart",
    "_token": "SNkipeuJwfn58IWpFYWNRo9Fx1nGzJnwGXENaLR0"
}';
$request = json_decode($str);

foreach ( $request->addon as &$addon){
    $addon = json_decode($addon);
}
print_r($request);
```

RESULT

```
stdClass Object
(
    [addon] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => pepsi
                    [price] => 10
                    [created_at] => 2022-12-09T18:12:35.000000Z
                    [updated_at] => 2022-12-09T18:12:35.000000Z
                    [restaurant_id] => 1
                    [status] => 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Extra Cheese
                    [price] => 4
                    [created_at] => 2022-12-14T18:16:48.000000Z
                    [updated_at] => 2022-12-14T18:16:48.000000Z
                    [restaurant_id] => 1
                    [status] => 1
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [name] => Additional Fries
                    [price] => 14
                    [created_at] => 2022-12-14T18:17:48.000000Z
                    [updated_at] => 2022-12-14T18:17:48.000000Z
                    [restaurant_id] => 1
                    [status] => 1
                )

        )

    [product] => 1
    [type] => product
    [quantity] => 1
    [purchase_type] => addtocart
    [_token] => SNkipeuJwfn58IWpFYWNRo9Fx1nGzJnwGXENaLR0
)
```